# Remote Desktop for Mac - issue with JavaFX app - PDFBOX

Tags: macos, javafx, pdfbox, remote-desktop

I have written a JavaFX app running on Windows 10 machine in the office which has problems showing (painting/rendering) certain embedded controls such as a Pane with PdfBox when I connect to it with Remote Desktop for Mac. It shows only a black screen in the app instead of the pdf document.

When I connect using RDP from my Windows 10 machine at home to my Windows 10 machine at work, the app works just fine (the pdf is shown in the app).
I have the same problems using AnyDesk and Teamviewer.
The app only shows PDFs properly using a connection from Windows 10 to Windows 10 with Microsoft RDP.

It might be a JavaFX issue. Similar issues are described here (although not 100% identical):

- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8239589
- https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8229394

However, since I guess Microsoft Remote Desktop for Mac is using the same technology as the Windows Desktop client, I would have expected it to work fine.

I have a Mac Mini M1 running the latest OS (Monterey) at the time of writing this post. I am also using the latest Remote Desktop client for Mac.
This problem is not new and was also present in older releases.

I have tried to play around with screen resolutions, both on Host and Client but nothing good came out of those tests.
Disabled also hardware acceleration in Remote Desktop for Mac preferences but it didn't change anything.

The machine at the office has the following specs (which I cannot change nor update)

- Edizione Windows 10 Pro
- Versione 20H2
- Data installazione: ‎10/‎09/‎2021
- Build sistema operativo 19042.1415
- Esperienza Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.3920.0

Anyone else who has seen this problem and perhaps resolved it?
Could it be a bug in either PdfBox or Remote Desktop for Mac?

Except for the above issue, the Remote Desktop Client for Mac is working great (not lagging as TeamViewer or AnyDesk) and the user experience is phenomenal.

PS: While this might be considered a programming question (since I wrote the app with JavaFX) but it might be better to post on another forum? If yes, which one? On the other hand, many similar posts (look at the suggested thread on the right) have been upvoted despite not dealing with programming issues.

Thanks.

Comment: In case this issue is PDFBox in JavaFX specific (seems possible as commercial Swing-based PDF viewer alternatives such as [JPedal appear to have similar issues when embedded in JavaFX](https://support.idrsolutions.com/jpedal/faqs/can-the-jpedal-viewer-be-used-javafx)), then you might wish to try other PDF viewing technology accessible via JavaFX, such as [PDFViewerFX](https://github.com/Dansoftowner/PDFViewerFX) which renders the PDF using JavaScript in a JavaFX WebEngine.  There may also be native JavaFX PDF viewers, but I am not aware of any currently supported.

Comment: To find out whether it is a PDFBox problem, save the BufferedImage that is created by the PDFRenderer.

Answer (score 1):

How do you use PDFBox? I ask because this is not a JavaFX component. If you use a SwingNode for that it might be interesting to try one of my two PDFViewer demos here and see whether the problem persists.

https://github.com/mipastgt/JFXToolsAndDemos#awtimage

The difference is in how I do the rendering and maybe that makes a difference for your use-case too. But of course this is just a wild guess and I can't promise anything.

Comment: Yes, sorry I forgot to mention that I am relying on Swing Classes to make PDFBOX work.
Thanks. I will try out your examples and see if your rendering could resolve my problems and then revert back.

Comment: You should also use the latest EA JavaFX version, which is 18-ea+9 at the time of this writing, just to make sure you've got one of these critical bug fixes. (You haven't mentioned the Java and JavaFX version which you are currently using.)